# reactor.iterate seems to block a program with Py2exe

Tags: python, twisted, py2exe

I'm currently using an application in python which works quite well but when I'm converting it with py2exe, the application seems to be suspended at the first "reactor.iterate"

Each time I press Ctrl+C to stop the application, the error is always the same and the application seems to be bloqued on a "reactor.iterate(4)"

This problem never occur with normal python interpreter.

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical use of the reactor is *not* to call `reactor.iterate`.  It's hard to say why exactly you're getting the behavior you are without seeing your program, but for a wild guess, I'd say switching to `reactor.run` might help.

Comment: Thank you.

In fact the problem was elsewhere but the traceback guide me to a wrong way (reactor.iterate). 

However, I will investigage on the reactor.run.